# TypeError: __init__() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given) when subclassing Model class

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to create a simple neural network using Tensorflow and Keras.
When I try to instantiate a Model by subclassing the Model class

```
class TwoLayerFC(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, hidden_size, num_classes):
        super(TwoLayerFC, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = keras.layers.Dense(hidden_size,activation=tf.nn.relu)
        self.fc2 = keras.layers.Dense(num_classes)


    def call(self, x, training=None):
        x = tf.layers.flatten(x)
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)

        return x
```

This is how I test the network

```
def test_TwoLayerFC():
    tf.reset_default_graph()
    input_size, hidden_size, num_classes = 50, 42, 10
    model = TwoLayerFC(hidden_size, num_classes)
    with tf.device(device):
        x = tf.zeros((64, input_size))
        scores = model(x)

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        scores_np = sess.run(scores)
        print(scores_np.shape)
```

I get an error:

> TypeError: **init**() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)

I followed [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/models/Model) tutorial, and it seems that there should be two parameters.

Comment: what is your input shape?

Comment: Subclassing a class alone does not instantiate it; you must have a line similar to `x = TwoLayerFC(...)` somewhere, and if so, what arguments are you passing it?

Comment: Additional error: `self.fc2 = keras.layers.Dense(hidden_size, num_classes)`. `num_classes` isn't a valid parameter - Dense only accepts one positional argument which is the units

Comment: The subclass in your link, unlike the one shown above, doesn't define any additional parameters for `__init__`, so `x = MyModel()` would work fine. `x = TwoLayerFC()` will *not*, because you've defined `TwoLayerFC.__init__` to take two additional arguments that you aren't providing.

Comment: @chepner I add the edit, can you have a look?

Answer (score 0):

I read your code and I see a PyTorch model being created, including the mistake in the second `Dense` layer with two passed numbers.

Keras models should not follow the same logic of PyTorch models.

This model should be created like this:

```
input_tensor = Input(input_shape)
output_tensor = Flatten()(input_tensor)
output_tensor = Dense(hidden_size, activation='relu')(output_tensor)
output_tensor = Dense(num_classes)

model = keras.models.Model(input_tensor, output_tensor)
```

This `model` instance is ready to be compiled and trained:

```
 model.compile(optimizer=..., loss = ..., metrics=[...])
 model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=..., batch_size=..., ...)
```

There is no reason in Keras to subclass `Model`, unless you're a really advanced user trying some very unconventional things.

By the way, be careful not to mix `tf.keras.anything` with `keras.anything`. The first is a version of Keras maitained directly by tensorflow, while the second is original Keras. They're not exactly the same, tensorflow's version seems more buggy and mixing the two in the same code sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: thanks! Yeah, for this primer I want to use specifically `tf.keras.anything`. Your example works fine, but for the research sake I still want to understand why I was getting the error. I've updated the code - can you have a look, please?

Comment: Please help us help you. Show the error, and **where** if happens. Show the stack trace. --- To be honest, I wouldn't care much, subclassing `Model` is simply not something you do in Keras.

Comment: I figured out the problem - I used tf 1.5.0 - I've updated to the latest one and solved the problem. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Indeed, the question was not answered. At that time, subclassing in Keras was something new, now it's more common. But for solving the problem the question author must pass the entire stack trace. The error message alone does not show where the problem is, and there doesn't seem to be evident mistakes in the edited code.